# How to add more than one WHERE clause dynamically in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have five input fields i.e., skill, location, company, experience, and salary.  Based on user requirement I'll get the value from the database.  My question is, how to use where condition dynamically? Consider the user entering values in skill and company input fields, I want to get those values from database how to do that? Now I kept 20 if conditions to solve this

```
public function get_jobonline($skillname,$userid,$location)
{
    $company=$this->input->post('searchcompany');
    $experience=$this->input->post('experience');
    $salary=$this->input->post('salary');
    echo $company;
    if($location==NULL)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT j.id AS job_id, j.created_date,j.title, l.city AS location, cm.name AS company_name,
        cm.logo FROM  `jobs` AS j
        LEFT JOIN  `keyword` AS k ON  `k`.`job_id` =  `j`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN  `keyword_master` AS km ON  `km`.`id` =  `k`.`keyword_id` 
        LEFT JOIN  `location_master` AS l ON  `l`.`id` =  `j`.`location` 
        LEFT JOIN  `company_master` AS cm ON  `cm`.`id` =  `j`.`company_id` 
        WHERE km.name = '$skillname' AND j.uid='$userid'
        ;");
    }
    else
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT j.id AS job_id, j.created_date,j.title, l.city AS location, cm.name AS company_name,
        cm.logo FROM  `jobs` AS j
        LEFT JOIN  `keyword` AS k ON  `k`.`job_id` =  `j`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN  `keyword_master` AS km ON  `km`.`id` =  `k`.`keyword_id` 
        LEFT JOIN  `location_master` AS l ON  `l`.`id` =  `j`.`location` 
        LEFT JOIN  `company_master` AS cm ON  `cm`.`id` =  `j`.`company_id` 
        WHERE km.name = '$skillname' AND j.uid='$userid' AND l.city='$location'
        ;");
    }

    // if($company != NULL && )

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: use AND / OR operators!!

Comment: This question is too vague to be answered in a good manner. It basically asks: how do WHERE operators in SQL queries work. Try to make your question more specific, for example by adding a relevant part of your code. That might help to get a meaningful answer that does help with your _real_ question.

Comment: side note: use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) if you can... you're asking for a SQLinjection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i had understand correctly u want to dynamically change your query depending on user input.
To do this u should separate the query itself AND the function that query.

Ex in pseudo CODE :

```
// Let's suppose it's your base query 
// (that meets the minimum field required to do the research).
$sql = "SELECT j.id AS job_id, j.created_date,j.title,... WHERE 
         km.name = '$skillname'";

// U add the condition skill if the user typed it
if(isset($_POST['skill'])
    $sql .= "AND j.skill = '$_POST['skill']'";

... (for every input filled u add condition to the query)

// WHEN all input u needed to add are tested
// Query the DB
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

U can even do better by makin an array that contains all the input name field in order to loop onto it.

Answer (score 1):

Queries are strings (almost, read on). You can create them with string processing. If you look at queries generated by software like this, you'll find they often read

```
 WHERE 1=1 AND name='value' and address = 'street' and job = 'driver'
```

etc. The `WHERE 1=1` part of that is a tipoff that the code used to generate the query works like this:

```
$q = "SELECT something JOIN something ON something...WHERE 1=1 ";
if (isset($val1))  $q .= " AND name= '$val1'";
if (isset($val2))  $q .= " AND street = '$val2'";
if (isset($val3))  $q .= " AND job = '$val3'";

if(!($result = db->query($q)) {
      /* error */
} else {
      /* process the resultset */
}
```

The `WHERE 1=1` is a hack to make sure the query is valid even if there are no search conditions: even if none of the `if` statements are true. It's slightly ugly, but SQL understands it and doesn't make the query take more time.

As you can see, this strategy adds a variable number of AND clauses to your query, dependent on the query parameters provided by your user.

There's only one problem with this example. It doesn't use bind variables so it's open to SQL injection. It's possible to work around that by building up a sequence of bind variables as well as a sequence of `AND column=?` clauses in your series of `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you,If i use the above method is it possible to add more than one AND clauses

Comment: Yes, that's the point of it.